# Creating input training data with an array of arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a NumPy array of 2500 14x14 matrices of floats between 0 and 1 (representing greyscale values). So for example, d.images.values[0] => the first 14x14 matrix. I need to pass these values to a class called Perceptron, which accepts an Input array of matrices (an array of arrays basically), and a 2500x1 Target matrix.

So a simple working example I have is:

```
I = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
    T = np.array([0,0,0,1]) #1x4 matrix OR target
    p = Perceptron(2,1)
    p.train(I,T)
    print(p.test([0,0])) # => False
```

Now I just need to pass in my d.images.values as inputs, and a 2000x1 matrix of target values, which I'm doing with:

```
T = np.array(np.append(np.ones(500), np.zeros(2000)))
```

My immediate thought was to just make an empty NumPy array with the correct dimensions and iteratively fill it with values from d.images.values[0 through 2500] along the lines of:

```
I = np.empty([2500,196])
for j in range(2500):
    I[j] = d.images[j].values
```

I know I don't have the syntax right, I'm relatively new to NumPy, but after pouring through the docs I still can't find a great way to do this.

My empty array may also be wrong, as I get the error:

```
  index 2500 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2500
```

Most of my attempts based on other SO questions and the docs' examples have been unsuccessful, either because the dimensions are off (I don't have the error in my console anymore and I wasn't able to recreate it), the array is appended without maintaining the sub arrays, or I get the error, which makes me think I need to fix the inputs' element datatypes with np.replace() or something of the like:

```
 Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Apologies if I haven't explained this very well, I've been up for about 48 hours and I'm a tad delirious at this point. Thanks for the help.

Comment: index 2500  would mean you had 2501 elements not 2500, `a = np.array([1,2,3]);a[a.size] -> indexError`, you would not include the upper bound of size.

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on how to turn the inputs into an array of matrices for the training?

Comment: what is the shape of d.images?

Comment: its a NumPy array of 2500 14x14 matrices. for example, d.images.values[0] returns the first 14x14 matrix.

Comment: What does  `d.images.value.shape` return?

Comment: d.images.values.shape throws an error since we're not specifying one image's values. On the other hand, d.images[0].values.shape returns (196,)

Comment: Sorry I meant `images.shape`